# How to obtain a complete list of US stock tickers using Alpha Vantage?

Tags: finance

I am trying to obtain a complete list of US stock tickers using the Alpha Vantage API. I have obtained an API key from Alpha Vantage, but I am unsure of how to properly make the request to get the full list.

Which endpoints should I use, and what parameters should I include in the request to get a comprehensive list of US stock tickers?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

To get a complete list tickers, you can use `LISTING_STATUS`:

```python
import requests

def get_listing_status(api_key):
    base_url = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query"
    function = "LISTING_STATUS"

    # Construct the API request URL
    api_url = f"{base_url}?function={function}&apikey={api_key}"

    # Send the API request and get the response
    response = requests.get(api_url)

    # Check if the request was successful
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.text
    else:
        return None

api_key = 'YOUR_API_KEY'
data = get_listing_status(api_key)
```

**Sample output**:

```
symbol,name,exchange,assetType,ipoDate,delistingDate,status
A,Agilent Technologies Inc,NYSE,Stock,1999-11-18,null,Active
AA,Alcoa Corp,NYSE,Stock,2016-10-18,null,Active
AAA,AXS First Priority CLO Bond ETF,NYSE ARCA,ETF,2020-09-09,null,Active
AAAU,Goldman Sachs Physical Gold ETF,BATS,ETF,2018-08-15,null,Active
AACG,ATA Creativity Global,NASDAQ,Stock,2008-01-29,null,Active
AACI,Armada Acquisition Corp I,NASDAQ,Stock,2021-11-10,null,Active
AACIU,Armada Acquisition Corp I - Units (1 Ord & 1/2 War),NASDAQ,Stock,2021-08-13,null,Active
AACIW,Armada Acquisition Corp I - Warrants (13/08/2026),NASDAQ,Stock,2021-11-11,null,Active
AACT,Ares Acquisition Corporation II - Class A,NYSE,Stock,2023-06-12,null,Active
```